# NSString hash collision doesn't mess up NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, nsdictionary

Run this code in the debugger and stop afterward (I'm in the iOS 7 simulator in Xcode 5.0.1).

```
NSString *nsStr = @"/Users/123456789012/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/94F31827-6DAD-4BD5-AC91-B215176265E1/Documents/libraries/shared/17517_abPub/OEBPS/indexes/Index.sqlite";
NSString *nsStr2 = @"/Users/123456789012/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/94F31827-6DAD-4BD5-AC91-B215176265E1/Documents/libraries/shared/16583_abPub/OEBPS/indexes/Index.sqlite";
NSUInteger form1 = [nsStr hash];
NSUInteger form2 = [nsStr2 hash];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
[dict setObject:@"foo" forKey:nsStr];

id foobar = [dict objectForKey:nsStr2];
```

Note that `form1` and `form2` are the same.  We have a hash collision.  Also note that `foobar` is `nil`.  The hash collision does not faze `NSDictionary`.  Why is this?  Does anyone know what Apple is doing to survive hash collision in their dictionary / what some good strategies are for this?

EDIT: For reference, [here](https://gist.github.com/fphilipe/3413755) is more detail on NSString hashing.  Apparently the method only looks at the first, middle, and last 32 characters; anything else in the string doesn't matter.

Comment: Why did you expect that it would break? Even simple dictionary implementations need to deal with hash collisions.

Comment: Right.  My experience with dictionary implementations used better hashes like MD5, so I guess I was expecting the NSString hash to be better.

Comment: Is your expectation that the hash of the key object is what's used as the actual key?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I was unthinkingly assuming that, yes.  But it makes sense that you can solve hash collisions easily and thus enable optimization of the hash algorithm for speed over uniqueness.

Comment: If you are really curious, you can inspect the implementation: https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFDictionary.c.

Comment: A hash code is an integer, it may have for example 4 bytes. A string long 1000 characters is 2KB if it contains all unichars. How is supposed the hash to map all the possible values of the strings? A hash code cannot be unique for all strings, it is used to distribute (that is for example, to choose in which list to put the string inside the dictionary, if it is implemented with an array of lists), not for unique identification.

Comment: I'm not getting why this is downvoted. This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `hash` value is not unique. Many different values can have the same hash value. The implementation of the dictionary knows this. The use of the hash is simply a way to optimize the lookup. But it's the actual key value that matters, not the hash value.

As long as any two objects that return `YES` to `isEqual:` also have the same `hash`, things are fine.

Think of a dictionary as a series of buckets. The hash determines which bucket the value is in. Once you know the bucket, you still need to look for the exact key.