# Does anyone know two NSString_s with the same hashes?

Tags: objective-c, hash, nsstring, md5, equality

I want to test some cases in my app with strings which have the same hash, and I can't find it =(

I've found two strings with the same MD5. [here](http://marc-stevens.nl/research/md5-1block-collision/) But their hash are different. And googling didn't help me =(

[NSString(MD5)](https://github.com/H2CO3/NSString-MD5) category

[Little story about NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19281755/1401067)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSString *string1 = [self fileContentWithName:@"message1" encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    NSString *string2 = [self fileContentWithName:@"message2" encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];

    if (string1 != nil) {
        if (string1.hash == string2.hash) {
            NSLog(@"Hashes are the same");
        } else {
            if ([[string1 MD5Hash] isEqualToString:[string2 MD5Hash]]) {
                NSLog(@"MD5 hases are equalfor:");
                NSLog(@"lenght = %3ld - %@", string1.length, string1);
                NSLog(@"lenght = %3ld - %@", string2.length, string2);
                if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2]) {
                    NSLog(@"Strings are equal too");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"But strings are not equal");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark -

- (NSString*)fileContentWithName:(NSString*)name encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
{
    NSString *txtFilePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"bin"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *txtFileContents1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath1 encoding:enc error:&error];
    return txtFileContents1;
}
```

Comment: Why can't they actually be the same strings?  What exactly are you testing?

Comment: That's absolut valid behavior. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756004/can-two-different-strings-generate-the-same-md5-hash-code).

Comment: You are absolutely right. And I was reading this question an hour ago. I just wanted to show "My researching way". Something like this...

Comment: @trojanfoe It is "researching work", and I want to test something like NSDictionary behavior with such keys